# Integrate Avaya IVRS with Service now using rest web-service

Tags: java, rest, servicenow, avaya

I have to integrate Avaya IVRS with Service now through java rest web-service. If user calls through Avaya IVRS, he should have option to choose from menu via their phone keypad and do the following functions :- 1. Add a ticket 2. Update a ticket 3. Close a ticket
    I have written code to create and update ticket but i don't know how to integrate with service now.

```
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // POST OPERATION -- Create a new Incident ticket
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  String endpointPOST = baseURI + "/in";
  PostMethod post = new PostMethod(endpointPOST);
  post.addRequestHeader("X-AccessKey", accessKey);
  post.addRequestHeader("Accept" , "application/xml");
  post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
  post.setRequestBody("<in>" + "<customer COMMON_NAME=\"System_SD_User\"/>" +
  "<description>Created from REST API Java Samples code</description>" + "</in>");
  try {
     System.out.println("Execute POST request for " + endpointPOST);
     // Execute POST request
     int result = client.executeMethod(post);
     System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
     System.out.println("Response body: ");
     System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
     System.out.println();
  } catch (HttpException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     post.releaseConnection();
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // PUT OPERATION -- Update an existing Incident ticket
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  String endpointPUT = baseURI + "/in/400001";
  PutMethod put = new PutMethod(endpointPUT);
  put.addRequestHeader("X-AccessKey", accessKey);
  put.addRequestHeader("Accept" , "application/xml");
  put.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
  put.setRequestBody(
  "<in>" +  "<summary>Updated from REST API Java Samples code</summary>" +  "</in>");
  try {
     System.out.println("Execute PUT request for " + endpointPUT);
     // Execute PUT request
     int result = client.executeMethod(put);
     System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
     System.out.println("Response body: ");
     System.out.println(put.getResponseBodyAsString());
     System.out.println();
  } catch (HttpException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     put.releaseConnection();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can integrate REST API default option given in OD or you can write customize java code  or create a jar of your application call that in OD

try the below code it's tested in Avaya lab

```
String webServiceURl="https://XXXXXXXXXX/services/OceanaDataoceana/data/context/schema";
    try{

        URL url = new URL(webServiceURl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    String input ="{""}";//pass paramenter for request
                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        System.out.println("conn.getResponseCode() ::::"+conn.getResponseCode());
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject object;
            try {
                object = new JSONObject(output);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("json response::: "+output);


        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Experience Portal then you have two choices. You can use the Orchestration Designer's built-in REST client (File/New/Web Service Operation File (REST)) or you implement it in a separate project and attach the rest client to your OD project.

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure Rest API from service end?